# Drupal 7 rebuild_menu, drupal crashed after module installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I just installed the module "Date" and after enabling drupal gave me the error: Enable Date API first, so i enabled the Date API and then the Date module and now drupal crashed and it says "Page not found" and i dont have any menu in the admin panel.

Menu rebuild does not work, i created an script for it without result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by restoring my sql backup. Not a good fix but yea...

Answer (score 0):

1. Restore from your most recent backup which you should have made before installing a new module.  ( Note:Drupal is not for amateurs, despite what they say. Drupal does not have professional governance, like say Wordpress, and that makes it relatively demanding for the inexperienced. With Drupal you really need to be sit next to a helpful pro for a year.)
2. Check that the version of PHP , Drupal, MySQL and the Date module are all compatible. This is work, BTW. If not compatible, then reinstall where necessary and cross your fingers.
3. Check for known issues by Googling something like or based on "Drupal 7 Date module".  Drupal 7 is old and issues that have arisen with so-called compatible modules may be well-documented.

Comment: Its a school exercise and i am not an amateur. I do not have a recent backup because my hosting does not support it. Give a working solution please

Comment: If you could install those modules you can also install Backup&Migrate.

Comment: Sorry to patronise you but I gave you a working solution then you executed it and it worked. I've put the work in.  Do the right thing, please.